# How to append to objects together in javascript

Tags: javascript, lodash

**I want to append an object of objects to another object of objects like so:**

```
object1: {
   item1: {},
   item2: {}
}

to 

object2: {
   item3: {},
   item4: {}
}
```

**So that the outcome is this:**

```
object1: {
   item1: {},
   item2: {},
   item3: {},
   item4: {}
}
```

I need to do this in javascript and can also use lodash as an option.

Comment: Before asking trivial questions such as this one, please read the docs, search using google, and then search again (research).

Answer (score 3):

Use `Object.assign()` function:

```
Object.assign(object1, object2);
```

Also, to make in portable, you can use lodash lib:

```
_.assign(object1, object2);
```

If you want to create new object, instead of mutating existing one, you can provide `{}` as first argument:

```
_.assign({}, object1, object2);
```

Comment: This won't work in IE, and isn't very portable.

Comment: They wanted to mutate the properties of `object1`. Don't use the `{}`

Comment: @4castle, thanks, I'll update answer.